# C#.net batch process

Tags: c#, concurrency, batch-file

I would like to know how can I go about programming in C#.net, if I wan to execute two tasks at the same time? Its a batch job so performance matters as well.

Comment: learn about threads in c# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: You can use Dot Net framework 4.0 "Parallel programming" feature. See the sample in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/06/01/parallel-programming-in-net-framework-4-getting-started.aspx Infact if the your system has multiple processor it will utlize them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET framework 4 or 4.5....Better use Task class instead of Thread. Task uses TPL and create appropriate number of threads based on the underlying hardware and gives you performance benefit if you run the program of multi core machine.

Answer (score 0):

You have two tools for that: Task and Thread. In most case, Thread is quite enough.

It's as simple as:

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(delegateMethod);
myThread.Start();
```

You can start as many as you want, and they will run in parallel, as long as your hardware can supply them.